# How to make widgets, TabView, and dynamic widgets(added with additional loads) inside TabBarView stay together with one Scrollcontroller in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to create a TabView within a Column that has other widgets fixed on top and a bot. Each tab should be able to load more data continuously (adding more rows). when switching to different tabs, it should display the data of the last opened tab(old scroll position). The basic widget structure is as follows:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  super.build(context);

  return Container(
    color: Colors.orange,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        // Fixed widgets on top
        Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                // widgets
                TabBar(
                  controller: _tabBarController,
                  tabs: [
                    // Tab widgets
                  ],
                ),
                TabBarView(
                  controller: _tabBarController,
                  children: [
                    // Widgets that can load more data
                  ],
                ),
                // widgets (in this case, a loading widget)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

However, when using the above code, I'm encountering the following error:

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
Assertion failed: file:///D:/Program/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1966:12
hasSize
"RenderBox was not laid out: RenderMouseRegion#af408 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT"
```

If I use Expanded with TabBarView, I get the following error:

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
Assertion failed: file:///D:/Program/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1966:12
hasSize
"RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#89637 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE"
```

Currently, the only way I can make it work is by manually setting the height of TabBarView using state management, and adjusting the height based on the size of the loaded widgets. Is there any way to avoid manually changing the height of TabBarView and dynamically adjusting it according to the size of the loaded widgets? (This won't work for widgets these don't know the size in advance.)

This is an example of How I fix it at this moment:

```
                  Obx(() => SizedBox(
                        height: _currentImageTabIndex.value == 0 ? _imageGridHeight.value : _imageTagGridHeight.value,
                        child: TabBarView(controller: _imageTabBarController, children: [
                          _imageListWidget,
                          _imageTagListWidget,
                        ]),
                      )),
```

My example [video](https://github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com/59549741/256995574-079b6458-01d6-4ff9-aacb-47f50c7b689e.mp4) of what I am doing.

```
0:08 - 0:20 = This page is just a tab.
0:20 - 0:30 = This top bar is fixed at the top.
0:30 - 0:50 = These widgets stay in the Column the same as the TabBar(on top). All widgets below the top bar are using the same scroll.
0:50 - 0:55 = This (loading)widget always stays at the bottom. The widgets inside the TabBarView can be added, and the scroll can reach these.
0:55 - 1:58 = When moving to another tab, the page should show the last position before the user moves to another tab.
```

For full template code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:issue_tabbarview_in_column/main/_share/dynamic_content_in_tab_widget.dart';
import 'package:issue_tabbarview_in_column/main/_share/fixed_top_widget.dart';
import 'package:issue_tabbarview_in_column/main/_share/title_widget.dart';
import 'package:issue_tabbarview_in_column/setting/page_path.dart';

class TemplatePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TemplatePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<TemplatePage> createState() => _TemplatePageState();
}

class _TemplatePageState extends State<TemplatePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final scrollController = ScrollController();
  late final TabController _tabBarController;
  int _itemCount1 = 0;
  int _itemCount2 = 0;

  late final tabBarWidget = TabBar(controller: _tabBarController, tabs: const [
    Tab(child: Icon(Icons.grid_on, color: Colors.black)),
    Tab(child: Icon(Icons.account_box_outlined, color: Colors.black)),
  ]);

  Future _onScrollDisable() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
    if (_itemCount1 != 0 && _itemCount2 != 0 && scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent != 0) return;
    _itemCount1 += 10;
    _itemCount2 += 10;
    setState(() {});
    await _onScrollDisable();
  }

  void _onScrollMax() {
    if (scrollController.position.pixels == scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) _tabBarController.index == 0 ? _itemCount1 += 10 : _itemCount2 += 10;
    setState(() {});
    print("_itemCount1: $_itemCount1");
    print("_itemCount2: $_itemCount2");
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabBarController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    _onScrollDisable().then((_) => scrollController.addListener(_onScrollMax));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabBarController.dispose();
    scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tabBarViewWidget = TabBarView(controller: _tabBarController, children: [
      DynamicContentInTabWidget(itemCount: _itemCount1),
      DynamicContentInTabWidget(itemCount: _itemCount2),
    ]);

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: InkWell(onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, PagePath.index), child: const Text("Template Page"))),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            const FixedTopWidget(),
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: scrollController,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const TitleWidget(),
                    tabBarWidget,
                    SizedBox(height: 1000, child: tabBarViewWidget), //I want to remove SizedBox with using auto height.
                    const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )));
  }
}

class TitleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const TitleWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: Colors.green,
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 400,
      child: const Text("Title Widget"),
    );
  }
}

class FixedTopWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const FixedTopWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: Colors.red,
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 100,
      child: const Text("Fixed Top Widget"),
    );
  }
}

class DynamicContentInTabWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int itemCount;
  final bool showLoading;

  const DynamicContentInTabWidget({super.key, required this.itemCount, this.showLoading = false});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: showLoading ? itemCount + 1 : itemCount,
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3, childAspectRatio: 1.0, crossAxisSpacing: 1, mainAxisSpacing: 1),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        if (showLoading && index == itemCount) const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        return Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: Colors.primaries[index % Colors.primaries.length],
          height: 100,
          child: Text('grid item $index'),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `NestedScrollView` widget helps in this scenario.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html

Here's a sample `build` method that achieves the target behavior (see comments):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  /// The layout is a column.
  return Column(
    children: [
      /// The fixed content is placed outside of the [Expanded] widget and
      /// given a fixed height.
      Container(
        height: 80.0,
        color: Colors.amber,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: const Text("Fixed content"),
      ),
      Expanded(
        /// This is the equivalent to your SingleChildScrollView.
        child: NestedScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          /// Any content that should collapse when scrolling should be placed
          /// inside of the [headerSliverBuilder].
          headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return [
              /// This is the profile part of the layout; show user data,
              /// announcements, etc.
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Container(
                  height: 144.0,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: const Text("Content: profile picture, name, etc."),
                ),
              ),

              /// This is the tab bar to switch between the two tabs.
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: TabBar(
                  controller: _tabBarController,
                  labelColor: Colors.black,
                  tabs: const [
                    Tab(child: Text("1")),
                    Tab(child: Text("2")),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: TabBarView(
            controller: _tabBarController,
            children: const [
              TestListView(count: 20),
              TestListView(count: 100),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

The `TestListView` class is used to test tabs with different heights (scroll offsets).

```
class TestListView extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestListView({super.key, required this.count});

  final int count;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(),
      itemCount: count,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return SizedBox(height: 40.0, child: Text("Item $index"));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

In order to restore the scroll offset, simply map a tab to a scroll offset (save `_scrollController.offset`), then restore it using the `onTap` handler of the `TabBar`.

Comment: This did not work when I changed `TestListView` with my widget.
But I read the docs from your link and that is what I want.
I will try and update the answer.

Comment: Your example does not work with the dynamic count.
I will read more doc.

Comment: The NestedScrollView can use tabbar without config the height. But the scroll controller of ListView inside TabBarView is not the same as this. So, I can't check if this scroll is to the max of the scroll bar. This issue can be fixed by placing scrollColtroller to children widgets in TabBarView but the scrollerController will separate and I don't want to separate this.

Comment: @SittiphanSittisak I used `TestListView` as an example widget, because the code for your widget is not there, so please include it if you can. What do you mean by it doesn't work with dynamic count? Please add the information to your question.

Comment: The dynamic count means the value added in the `TestListView` isn't Constance, this value can change and add the item in the `TestListView`. I have added the template code to this question.